# Do AdWords conversions only track AdWords visitors?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-ads, conversions

I have set up an AdWords conversion and put the conversion tracking JS code on a test page.

However, I don't see any conversions tracked when I visit it.

**Does the AdWords conversion tracking only register your conversion if you come to the site by clicking on an AdWords campaign?**

Google's help page advises me to test the code by clicking a campaign.

However, I would like to use the tracking to track all conversions, not just AdWords. I considered using Analytics as well, but it seems you can only track via url there, not JS, which would mean I had to restructure a part of my page. (Because currently a conversion appears does not necessarily happen on a different URL.)

Is AdWords tracking not a viable solution to track all visitor conversions  on my site?

Comment: You may find this helpful http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91171/why-do-we-need-to-setup-additional-conversion-tracking-code-in-adwords-if-we-alr/91177#91177

Answer (score 1):

Conversions shown in AdWords are just those visitors that have converted on your website via clicking on one of your ads in Google, yes.

It is possible to do what you want with Google Analytics goals though but you should create a new question for this with more details as to exactly what you're wanting to do and track.

Answer (score 1):

Adwords conversion tracking tracks conversions of Adwords, that can be seen on the Adwords platform. But it doesn't mean that you don't want to see these goals on Google Analytics as well. Anyhow, In your case you indeed have to use Google Analytics and track conversions as **goals**, and those will get conversion of visitors from Adwords as well as of any other traffic source.

If you don't have a separate page that marks conversion you can make either a:

1) Virtual page view - inject a Google Analytics JS code that simulates a virtual page view (in other words, as if the user visited a new page) based on an action of a user (click or form submit), and this way you can create the conversion page.

2) Record the conversion as an Google Analytics event (again, can be triggered by a click or any other user action), and this event you can later set as goal on Google Analytics.

You can use either, depends on your needs. Links to implementation of these methods can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032720?hl=en

Having said the above, you can also import your conversions from Google Analytics to Adwords, but it has some disadvantages: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034306?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Both AdWords and Google Analytics can record conversions using either destination URL page view or event tracking.

Goals (conversions) inside Google Analytics- can use event tracking javascript code by editing the website- and adding in the extra JS code. 
Using Google Tag Manager to deploy the Google Analytics event tracking is easier than editing the code.