# Why do we need to setup additional conversion tracking code in AdWords if we already trigger conversions in GA code?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, conversions

A client is using `ga('ecommerce:` calls throughout their codebase. Conversions show up in Google Analytics under *Conversions » Ecommerce*, and revenue amounts show up correctly wherever there is a column for it.

We've setup a new AdWords campaign and linked the AdWords and Analytics accounts. I've enabled auto tagging for the account. I've imported all of my existing goals and transactions.

**There's a little warning telling me that the AdWords conversion code hasn't been installed.** Why do I need AdWords conversion code to run if:

1. The user clicks a link and visits `example.com/foo`
2. GA sends the page view, tracking the user, and knowing that they were referred to this page from the ad click.
3. The user buys something. The conversion is triggered. This is reflected in GA.

If this was all setup and married together, why do I need to add additional conversion tracking code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question and I'm not going to be able to explain it as well as some other users who might comment later but I'll let you know what I know.

As you might know Analytics and Adwords are separate and the data they record is different. Adwords code is different because its more cookie orientated - following the user based of the gclid of the ad they clicked on to see if they convert.

Analytics doesn't take into consideration gclid tracking and I am complete unaware why its not just apart of the Analytics code whether you have Adwords or not. That unfortunately will have to be answer by someone else with more Technical Google knowledge.

One thing that is certain is that you need both if you want to track your GA goal conversions as well as your Adwords conversions. The paid conversions analytics is critical for see if ads are converting at a viable rate - you mightn't be paying much for lots of views but if you are getting no return or you are converting from organic customers only then your ads need to change or you need to stop advertising because if you aren't making more money then without the Ads then they aren't worth it right.

SUMMARY: You need both sets of tracking codes